# UDF for array formulas created from macro

Tags: vba, udf

I want to create a udf for a formula I have written on excel.  The formula is as follows:

```
=INDEX('Pivot-LH'!$D$5:$D$1650,SMALL(IF(B93='Pivot-LH'!$A$5:'Pivot-LH'!$A$1650,ROW('Pivot-LH'!$A$5:'Pivot-LH'!$A$1650)-ROW('Pivot-LH'!$A$5)+2),1))
```

Basically the syntax is to look for cell B93 (variable) through some data on Pivot-LH sheet and return the 1st, 2nd and 3rd values.

I want to define a udf for this and tried to do this by recording a macro. It gave the following result which I modified to enter B93 as a variable called newroute. However this always gives the value zero:

```
Public Function LH(newroute As Range) As Variant

Selection.FormulaArray = "=INDEX(R5C4:R1650C4,SMALL(IF(newroute=R5C1:R1650C1,ROW(R5C1:R1650C1)-ROW(R5C1)+2),1))"

End Function
```

Why does it not give the same result as the formula?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call `LH` from a worksheet formula, your function can only return a value.  It cannot update the sheet directly.

See:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170787

> A user-defined function called by a formula in a worksheet cell cannot
>   change the environment of Microsoft Excel. This means that such a
>   function cannot do any of the following:
>
> - Insert, delete, or format cells on the spreadsheet.
> - Change another cell's value.
> - Move, rename, delete, or add sheets to a workbook.
> - Change any of the environment options, such as calculation mode or screen views.
> - Add names to a workbook.
> - Set properties or execute most methods.

So you need something like:

```
Public Function LH(newroute As Range) As Variant

    LH = newroute.Parent.Evaluate("=INDEX(R5C4:R1650C4,SMALL(IF(" & _
                              newroute.Address() & _
            "=R5C1:R1650C1,ROW(R5C1:R1650C1)-ROW(R5C1)+2),1))"

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @timWilliams. I understand your point. I am still facing the issue that the formula is returning a #Value error. I am now entering:
'
Public Function LH(newroute As Range)

    LH = newroute.Parent.Evaluate("=INDEX('Pivot-LH'!R5C5:R1650C5,SMALL(IF(" & _
                              newroute.Address() & _
            "='Pivot-LH'!R5C2:'Pivot-LH'!R1650C2,ROW('Pivot-LH'!R5C2:'Pivot-LH'!R1650C2)-ROW('Pivot-LH'!R5C2)+1),1))")
            
End Function'

I am sure i am making a small mistake somewhere.

Comment: Are all of the ranges involved on the same worksheet?

Comment: They are in different sheets, but even if I put the ranges in the same sheet I continue to get the error.

Comment: Debug.print the formula text and try debugging it on the worksheet.

Comment: Hi @timwilliams, I have created a template worksheet with my issue. Can you please look into it. I will be grateful.
[link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/c7c34uhx3f0k7en/Template.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do in that workbook. I hardly ever us R1C1 notation, so maybe you can switch to A1 style.  I notice you changed the `.Address()` to `.Value` though: if you do that then you need to quote the value in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Public Function LH(newroute As Range) As Variant

Selection.FormulaArray = "=INDEX(R5C4:R1650C4,SMALL(IF(" & newroute.address & "=R5C1:R1650C1,ROW(R5C1:R1650C1)-ROW(R5C1)+2),1))"

End Function
```