# ADO Recordset exits VBA Function when writing to excel but works as a Sub

Tags: excel, ms-access, ado, adodb

Using Excel 2016 64bit with an Access DB. I created a function that gets historical data from the DB. It runs in the debug window and populates the recordset. But as soon as I try and write the data to an excel sheet, VBA just exits without an error.

I've tried several different ways of populating the data into excel including .copyfromrecordset, converting the data to strings, passing to a temporary variable. No luck. If I run the same code (adjusted as needed) as a Sub, it works perfectly. If I try passing the values to a sub first, and then to the worksheet, it also fails. It fails as long as a function is involved. I've searched for answers and can't find anything. Any ideas?

```
Function DAM_DD(Type_input As String, Tenor_input As String, Field_output As String, Optional Date_input As String, Optional Date_input2 As String, Optional target_cell As Range) As Variant
  Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
  Dim stQuery As String, tbl_input As String, tenor_coupon As String

'<<< Bunch of code to fill in sql variables >>>

stQuery = "Select " & Field_output & " From " & tbl_input & " Where (" & 
Date_input & " and Type=""" & Type_input & """ and " & tenor_coupon & ");"

'Execute query and return to a recordset
    Call DAM_DB_Connection(stQuery, rst, cnt)

'Return results to excel
    If rst.RecordCount <= 1 Then
       DAM_DD = rst.Fields(0).Value
    Else: Call Get_DAM_Hist(rst, target_cell)
    End If

'Close database connection and clean up
    Call Close_DB(rst, cnt)
End Function

Sub DAM_DB_Connection(stQuery As String, rst As ADODB.Recordset, cnt As ADODB.Connection)
  Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
  Dim stcon As String 'SQL Connection string

  Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
  Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
  Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

'Define database connection string
    stcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;"    
    stcon = stcon + "Data Source='C:\Users\DAM_DB.accdb';"

'Open database connection
    cnt.ConnectionString = stcon
    cnt.Open
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.ActiveConnection = cnt 'Set the command connection string
    cmd.CommandText = stQuery 

'Execute query and return to a recordset
    rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient 'Needed for recordset count
    rst.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    rst.Open stQuery, cnt, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
    rst.MoveFirst

'Close connection in separate Sub Close_DB
End Sub

Sub Get_DAM_Hist(rst As ADODB.Recordset, target_cell As Range)
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim Rw As Long, Col As Long, rst_end As Long, counter As Long
  Dim rst_array As Variant, target_array As Variant

  Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
  rst_end = rst.RecordCount
  ReDim rst_array(0 To rst_end, 0 To rst_end)

  rst_array = rst.GetRows(rst.RecordCount)
  PrintArray rst_array, target_cell 

'    counter = 1
'    Do While rst.EOF = False
'            ws.Cells(counter, 8) = rst.Fields(0) <- Alternate version that fails Here
'            ws.Cells(counter, 9) = rst.Fields(1)
'            counter = counter + 1
'            rst.MoveNext
'    Loop
End Sub

Sub PrintArray(Data As Variant, target_cell As Range)
  Dim Rw As Integer, Cl As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
  Dim out_string As String

Rw = Range(target_cell).Row
Cl = Range(target_cell).Column

For i = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
    For j = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
        out_string = Trim(CStr(Data(i, j)))
        Activesheet.Cells(Rw, Cl) = out_string    '<--------- Fails here
        Cl = Cl + 1
    Next j
        Rw = Rw + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the links. The evaluate command worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

> If I run the same code (adjusted as needed) as a Sub, it works perfectly.

There are some limitations on UDF (user-defined functions) in VBA which prevent it from altering the environment, in a nutshell, you can't really operate against or write to cells or worksheets that aren't passed to the function, you can't output to other ranges, etc. So a function cannot output a recordset (or a portion thereof) to a worksheet. A function can't write an array to a worksheet, or even a single value to a different cell.

You can observe this most simply with a very basic function like below, which will always fail:

```
Option Explicit
Function myfunction(v)
    [A1].Value = v
    myfunction = 1
End Function
```

[Via Microsoft, for a longer explanation:](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel)

> A user-defined function called by a formula in a worksheet cell cannot
> change the environment of Microsoft Excel. This means that such a
> function cannot do any of the following:
>
> - Insert, delete, or format cells on the spreadsheet.
> - Change another cell's value. Move, rename, delete, or add sheets to a workbook.
> - Change any of the environment options, such as calculation mode or screen views.
> - Add names to a workbook.
> - Set properties or execute most methods.
>
> The purpose of
> user-defined functions is to allow the user to create a custom
> function that is not included in the functions that ship with
> Microsoft Excel. The functions included in Microsoft Excel also cannot
> change the environment. Functions can perform a calculation that
> returns either a value or text to the cell that they are entered in.
> Any environmental changes should be made through the use of a Visual
> Basic subroutine.
>
> During calculation, Excel examines the precedents of the cell that
> contains a user-defined function. If not all precedents have been
> calculated so far during the calculation process, Excel eventually
> calls the user-defined function and passes a Null or Empty cell to the
> function. Excel then makes sure that enough calculation passes occur
> for all precedents to be calculated. During the final calculation
> pass, the user-defined function is passed the current values of the
> cells. This can cause the user-defined function to be called more
> frequently than expected, and with unexpected arguments. Therefore,
> the user-defined function may return unexpected values.
>
> For correct calculation, all ranges that are used in the calculation
> should be passed to the function as arguments. If you do not pass the
> calculation ranges as arguments, instead of referring to the ranges
> within the VBA code of the function, Excel cannot account for them
> within the calculation engine. Therefore, Excel may not adequately
> calculate the workbook to make sure that all precedents are calculated
> before calculating the user-defined function.

## TL;DR

You can't run this as a function. Run it as a sub.

(technically, I believe there are ways to circumvent this limitation that work for at least some cases, but I usually wouldn't recommend them)

see here:

[Using a UDF in Excel to update the worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet/31720319#31720319)

and here:

[UDF for array formulas created from macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231915/udf-for-array-formulas-created-from-macro/39234025#39234025)

and here:

[Excel: Change background color of a cell to RGB color written in that cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716565/excel-change-background-color-of-a-cell-to-rgb-color-written-in-that-cell/31719591#31719591)